help with blank screen accessing gnome remote desktop (headless, 24.04, Raspi)
I'm trying to setup headless access to a raspberry Pi.  Server has new install of 24.04 server and gnome-desktop-minimal. gnome-remote-desktop is configured and running.
On access from an RDP client, the RDP username and password are accepted and a black screen appears for about 30s and then disappears.  Multiple clients behave the same way (remmina, Windows App for mac).  Syslog shows wayland successfully start a screensaver service, then a pause and then gnome-remote-desktop-daemon aborting handover (presumably of the incoming connection).  During the pause the process running gnome-remote-de is using around 100% of a CPU core.
Any ideas what is going wrong?
Adding new information:
Poking around in the gnome remote desktop code, it looks like there is a 30s timeout if the handover does not complete.  I haven't figured out how to turn on debug logging or what process should be accepting the handover and is failing, or how communication with it works.  Is the 100% cpu by the remote desktop daemon a busy/wait?
syslog exert:
Dec 29 15:26:39 astrobuntu xbrlapi.desktop[13695]: openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
Dec 29 15:26:39 astrobuntu xbrlapi.desktop[13695]: cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
Dec 29 15:26:39 astrobuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session[13116]: dbus-daemon[13116]: [session uid=124 pid=13116] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Dec 29 15:27:03 astrobuntu gnome-remote-de[2305]: [DaemonSystem] Aborting handover, removing remote client with remote id /org/gnome/RemoteDesktop/Client/1861712809
Dec 29 15:27:03 astrobuntu gnome-remote-desktop-daemon[2305]: [15:27:03:391] [2305:00000901] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.peer] - [rdp_set_error_info]: ERRINFO_CB_CONNECTION_CANCELLED [0x00010409]
Dec 29 15:27:09 astrobuntu systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 15:27:09 astrobuntu systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 15:27:39 astrobuntu geoclue[13625]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Dec 29 15:27:39 astrobuntu systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.


